# How to validate group of values in column B comparing to values from column A

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I need to validate that a specific rule is applied for a table.

Rule = all options (column OPTION_REF) linked to 1 customer (CUSTOMER_NR) should be identical

(Remark: customers can have 1 to 800 options linked, so just link table to itself is not applicable)

I need to detect customers for which not all options linked are identical.

```
CUSTOMER_NR  CONTRACT_NR  OPTION_REF
-------------------------------------
CUSTOMER1    CONTRACT1    OPTION A
CUSTOMER1    CONTRACT2    OPTION A
CUSTOMER1    CONTRACT3    OPTION A
CUSTOMER2    CONTRACT1    OPTION F
CUSTOMER2    CONTRACT2    OPTION F
CUSTOMER3    CONTRACT1    OPTION B
CUSTOMER3    CONTRACT2    OPTION T
CUSTOMER3    CONTRACT3    OPTION B
```

In the example above I need to retrieve 'CUSTOMER3' as result of my query, as 2 different options (OPTION B & OPTION T)  are linked to CUSTOMER3

Can someone help?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

try with this:

```
declare @data as table (customer varchar(50), cont varchar(50), opt varchar(50))
 insert into @data values
 ('CUSTOMER1', 'CONTRACT1', 'OPTION A'),
('CUSTOMER1', 'CONTRACT2', 'OPTION A'),
('CUSTOMER1', 'CONTRACT3', 'OPTION A'),
('CUSTOMER2', 'CONTRACT1', 'OPTION F'),
('CUSTOMER2', 'CONTRACT2', 'OPTION F'),
('CUSTOMER3', 'CONTRACT1', 'OPTION B'),
('CUSTOMER3', 'CONTRACT2', 'OPTION T'),
('CUSTOMER3', 'CONTRACT3', 'OPTION B')


select agregatedData.customer
from(
    select customer,opt
    from @data
    group by customer,opt
) as agregatedData
group by agregatedData.customer
having COUNT(0) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

SAS solution:

```
proc sort data=have out=sorted nodupkey;
by customer_nr option_ref;
run;

data want;
set sorted;
by customer_nr option_ref;
if not (first.customer_nr and last.customer_nr);
run;
```

Can also use PROC FREQ or whatever to aggregate, but sorting is just as easy since you don't care about counts per option unless it's a really massive dataset (in which case PROC FREQ/MEANS/whatnot may be faster).

If you actually only want CUSTOMER3 returned and don't even care about the two different options, then it's easier - no sort, assuming it's already sorted by CUSTOMER_NR as above.

```
data want;
set have;
by customer_nr option_ref notsorted;
if first.option_ref and not first.customer_nr;
run;
```

That won't return every record (it won't return the first option, specifically) but it will return at least one record for each difference (it may return many).

Answer (score 0):

SAS SQL Version:

```
data mydata;
  input customer $
        contract $
        option   $20.
        ;
datalines;
CUSTOMER1 CONTRACT1 OPTION A
CUSTOMER1 CONTRACT2 OPTION A
CUSTOMER1 CONTRACT3 OPTION A
CUSTOMER2 CONTRACT1 OPTION F
CUSTOMER2 CONTRACT2 OPTION F
CUSTOMER3 CONTRACT1 OPTION B
CUSTOMER3 CONTRACT2 OPTION T
CUSTOMER3 CONTRACT3 OPTION B
;
run;


**
** SUMMARY OF INVALID CUSTOMERS
*;
proc sql noprint;
  create table validation_summary as 
  select customer,
         count(distinct option) as number_unique_options
  from mydata
  group by 1
  having count(distinct option) > 1
  ;
quit;

**
** DETAILS OF INVALID CUSTOMERS
*;
proc sql noprint;
  create table validation_detail as 
  select distinct a.customer, a.option
  from mydata a
  where a.customer in (select b.customer 
                       from mydata b 
                       group by 1 
                       having count(distinct option) > 1
                      )
  ;
quit;
```

Note that this will return all of the options associated with the invalid configurations including the first.  In your requirements it looks like you want to ignore the first.  This could be easily done with a subsequent step if desired.